# Datepicker for iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, datepicker

How can I customize a UIDatePicker to only show the time? There's an existing mode that shows the day, month, and year, but I'd like to get rid of the day portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the mode, either to time, date, date and time, or count down timer in the interface builder.

In code you want `setDatePickerMode` and values are:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDatePickerMode) {
    UIDatePickerModeTime,           // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeDate,           // Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)
    UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,    // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer  // Displays hour and minute (e.g. 1 | 53)
};
```